# Unresolve reference 'registration' in urls.py

Tags: python, django, django-login

I use Django-Registration-Redux in my Django project.

In settings.py, the code:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'rango',
#'django.contrib.sites',
'registration',
```

In urls.py, the code:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

from django.conf.urls.static import static

from django.conf import settings

from registration.backends.simple.views import RegistrationView

# Create a new class that redirects the user to the index page, if         successful at logging
class MyRegistrationView(RegistrationView):
    def get_success_url(self,request, user):
        return '/rango/'


urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^rango/', include('rango.urls')),
#Add in this url pattern to override the default pattern in accounts.
url(r'^accounts/register/$', MyRegistrationView.as_view(),     name='registration_register'),
(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.simple.urls')),)

if not settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,     document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns(
    'django.views.static',
    (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)',
    'serve',
    {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),)
```

Then pyCharm show that my urls.py has errors:
Unresolve reference 'registration'

I have run 'python manage.py migrate'. But the error still exists.
Why does this happend? How can I fix it? And it's really strange that although pyCharm show error, my code run well.

PS: I write this code as the same as the django tutorial http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/login_redux.html

Comment: You should post your urls.py. The code you've posted appears to be from views.py.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have post both views.py and url.py. The second code is  a part of urls.py which involve this problem. Please look it.

Comment: Strange place to put it, but whatever. But why have you only posted *part* of urls.py? The error doesn't seem to be in that part. Post the whole thing.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Sorry, I have update it. And I found I can run my code wll although pyCharm show that error. It's strange.

Comment: [Reload](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/installing-uninstalling-and-reloading-interpreter-paths.html#d112263e172) the Interpreter Path so that PyCharm can pick up and new packages you have installed. I think you may need to that every time you update your virtualenv with new packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because PyCharm does not have the same sys.path as your django project.

To get rid of the false warning, mark your top-level django directory (the one that contains *manage.py*) as a directory that contain sources:

1. select the directory in pycharm, then right click
2. in the context menu, select **Mark Directory As** > **Sources Root**